# MySQL behavior of ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple UNIQUE fields

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert

From MySQL 4.1.0 onwards, it is possible to add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement to specify behavior when values inserted (with `INSERT` or `SET` or `VALUES`) are already in destination table w.r.t. `PRIMARY KEY` or some `UNIQUE` field. If value for `PRIMARY KEY` or some `UNIQUE` field are already in table, `INSERT` is replaced by an `UPDATE`.

- How does `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` behave in case there are multiple
  `UNIQUE` fields in my table ?
- Can I have one update only, if either `UNIQUE` field is matched ?
- Can I have an update only if both `UNIQUE` fields are matched simultaneously ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Consider

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

If a and b are `UNIQUE` fields, `UPDATE` occurs on `a = 1 OR b = 2`. Also when condition `a = 1 OR b = 2` is met by two or more entries, update is done only once.

Ex here table table with Id and Name `UNIQUE` fields

```
Id     Name     Value 
1      P        2 
2      C        3 
3      D        29 
4      A        6
```

If query is

```
INSERT INTO table (Id, Name, Value)
VALUES (1, C, 7);
```

then we get

```
Id     Name     Value 
1      P        2 
2      C        3 
3      D        29 
4      A        6
1      C        7
```

which violates uniqueness of Id and Name. Now with

```
INSERT INTO table (Id, Name, Value)
VALUES (1, C, 7)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value = 7;
```

we get

```
Id     Name     Value 
1      P        7 
2      C        7 
3      D        29 
4      A        6
```

**Behavior on multiple keys is the following**

`UPDATE` in `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is performed if one of the `UNIQUE` field equals the value to be inserted. Here, `UPDATE` is performed on `Id = 1 OR Name = C`. It is equivalent to

```
UPDATE table 
SET Value = 7
WHERE Id = 1 OR Name = C;
```

**What if I want one update only, for either key**

Can use `UPDATE` statement with `LIMIT` keyword

```
UPDATE table 
SET Value = 7
WHERE Id = 1 OR Name = C
LIMIT 1;
```

which will give

```
Id     Name     Value 
1      P        7 
2      C        3 
3      D        29 
4      A        6
```

**What if I want one update only if values for both keys are matched**

One solution is to `ALTER TABLE` and make the `PRIMARY KEY` (or uniqueness) work on both fields.

```
ALTER TABLE table 
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id, Name);
```

Now, on

```
INSERT INTO table (Id, Name, Value)
VALUES (1, C, 7)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value = 7;
```

we get

```
Id     Name     Value 
1      P        2 
2      C        3 
3      D        29 
4      A        6
1      C        7
```

since no duplicate (on both keys) is found.

Comment: If you have a table with two columns as primary key, and want work with the ON DUPLICATE KEY, must avoid add unique index to the pk columns, because this will update if pk1 or pk2 are present in the values.

Comment: Is there any way of having a unique constraint on the 2nd column, but have it so it does not affect this duplicate key update operation? This means the insert or update fails if the unique constraint is not met.

Comment: My tests contradict what this answer claims (on MySQL 8.0.22). **Only one duplicate row gets updated**, and it appears to be the row of the _first_ index on which a duplicate is found. Annoying, since it is hard to control index order, and index order _should not matter_. (Note that the PK is always the first unique index, so a PK duplicate will always be the first contender for the update - which is about the only thing about all this that feels logical.)

Answer (score 0):

1. how does MySQL behave ...
   It behaves as expected, that is executes ON DUPLICATE KEY clause.
2. Can I have one update for either...
   In reality, you have only one ON DUPLICATE KEY clause, so you need to put some code to differentiate which constraint was involved. Fortunatelly, it is possible. The only thing you should know, the order of assignment matters, and you can assign multiple times. Suppose, you have unique constraint on a and b, and you want to update c only if a uniqueness is involved:
       ...
       KEY UPDATE c = IF(a = VALUES(a) and b <> VALUES(b),  VALUES(c), c), b = VALUES(b)

   but if you change the order of assignments the second condition within if will be always false.
3. See 2.