# MySQL: How to update unique key on duplicate unique key

Tags: mysql

Given the following table structure, how can I change the value of `primary` to 0 when a duplicate unique index is found?

```
CREATE TABLE `ncur` (
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `rank_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `primary` TINYINT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `rank_id`),
    UNIQUE (`user_id`, `primary`)
);
```

So, when I run a query like this:

```
UPDATE `ncur` SET `primary` = 1 WHERE `user_id` = 4 AND `rank_id` = 5;
```

When a constraint of `user_id-primary` is matched, I want it to set all `primary` values for `user_id` to `NULL`, and then complete the update query by updating the row it had found.

Comment: A bit off topic but why have a unique constraint on user_id and a primary key on user_id and rank_id?

Comment: Because each `user_id` can have many `rank_id`'s (`PRIMARY`) and they are only allowed to have one `primary` (not null).

Comment: You are trying to update multiple rows in a statement that intends to only write/update one row. You will either need to handle this in your application, or alternatively, write an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY  statement for all rows with on user_id and use logic in the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause.

Comment: "I want it to set all primary values for user_id to 0.." 
Assuming this is done for a specific `user_id` the first time, the second time it will not be allowed as it will otherwise violate the UNIQUE constraint condition.

Comment: The unique index means that two rows for a given `user_id` cannot have the same `primary` value -- setting multiple rows to the same combination of values just isn't allowed.  It sounds like you want a filtered index/constraint, which MySQL does not directly support, although you can implement it using a trigger.

Comment: @RezaGoodarzi When it violates the unique constraint, I want it to change the values of `primary` of the specified `user_id` back to `NULL`. Then proceed with the update. @GordonLinoff, do you know a trigger that can accomplish this?

Comment: Ok saw my mistake. Too close to xmas to think properly makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377932/mysql-behavior-of-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-unique-fields

Comment: @AvinashBabu That pertains to duplicate keys when inserting, my query needs to update the duplicate indexes that are found before updating my query. Please, actually read my question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not as much familiar with MySQL as I am with Oracle; However, I think this query should work for you:

```
UPDATE `ncur` a
SET `primary` = (

    /* 1st Subquery */
    SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT * FROM `ncur`) b        
    WHERE b.`user_id` = a.`user_id` AND b.`rank_id` = a.`rank_id` 
                                                           AND a.`rank_id` = 5

    UNION ALL 

    /* 2nd Subquery */ 
    SELECT 0 FROM (SELECT * FROM `ncur`) b
    WHERE b.`user_id` = a.`user_id` AND b.`rank_id` <> 5 AND a.`rank_id` <> 5
    GROUP BY `user_id`
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) 
WHERE `user_id` = 4
```

Justification:

The query updates all the records that have `user_id = 4`.

For each of such records, `primary` is set to a different value of 1, 0, or NULL,  depending on the value of `rank_id` in this record as well as the information regarding how many other records with the same `user_id` exists in the table.

The subquery that returns the value for `primary` consists of three subqueries, only one of which returns a value depending on the circumstances.

- 1st Subquery: This subquery returns `1` for the record with `rank_id = 5`; Otherwise it returns `NULL`.
- 2nd Subquery: This subquery returns `0` for the records with `rank_id
  != 5` if there is only one such record in the table; otherwise it returns `NULL`.

Please note: if the query is run while there are no records with rank_id = 5, it will still update the other records according to the rules specified above. If this is not desired, the condition in the parent query must be changed from:

```
WHERE `user_id` = 4
```

to:

```
WHERE `user_id` = 4 AND 
      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `ncur`) b WHERE 'rank_id` = 5)
```