# Cannot get UPSERT to work on MYSQL with auto increment column and FK

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, innodb

I have an innodb table called word_frequency with 4 columns

1. ID - INT (pk) (auto_increment)
2. USER_ID - INT (fk)
3. WORD - STRING
4. FREQUENCY - INT

I have tried multiple different queries but cannot seem to perform an upsert properly. I only want to update the table when USER_ID and WORD both already exist, else new row. But It just keeps creating new rows with the auto increment ID.

```
INSERT INTO word_frequency (USER_ID, WORD, FREQUENCY)
    VALUES(1, "word", 32)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FREQUENCY = FREQUENCY + 27;
```

I even tried

```
INSERT INTO word_frequency (USER_ID, WORD, FREQUENCY)
        VALUES(1, "word", 32)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), FREQUENCY = FREQUENCY + 27;
```

and

```
 INSERT INTO word_frequency (ID,USER_ID, WORD, FREQUENCY)
        VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(ID+1),1, "word", 32)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), FREQUENCY = FREQUENCY + 27;
```

where am I going wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `upsert` what is it?

Comment: Upsert is update else insert @A-2-A

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377932/mysql-behavior-of-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-unique-fields

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a unique index on `WORD` field like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_WORD ON word_frequency (WORD );
```

This way MySQL *knows* that *no duplicates are allowed* on `WORD`. So, when `INSERT` tries to insert a word that already exists, then the `UPDATE` part of the query is executed.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba639/1)

Comment: This worked perfectly! makes sense now with your code snippet. I actually did the line CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_WORD ON word_frequency (USER_ID, WORD); as I wanted to allow the same word to exist if another user chose to insert it. This seems to work fine. thanks @Giorgos Betsos